# How to count co-ocurrences of strings in a pyspark column of strings?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of website navigation path logs and I want to count, for each possible pair of pages, the number of times they appear together in a session.

I have already generated 2 lists that provide all the possible combinations of 2 pages. I also have a list of sessions (strings), where each string is a sequence of pages separated by a comma.

Now I want to generate a list which will count, for each pair of pages, in how many sessions they appear together. I have tried this with a for loop that looks reasonable, but it's way too slow, even with a small sample (it's been turning for hours and it's not done yet).

```py
# This is what I have as input data:
list1 = ['page_a','page_a','page_a','page_b','page_b','page_c']
list2 = ['page_b','page_c','page_d','page_c','page_d','page_d']

sessions = ['page_a,page_b',
            'page_b,page_d,page_c',
            'page_b',
            'page_d,page_c,page_a,page_b,',

]

# This is the for loop I have tried, but that is way too slow:
coocurrence = []
for i in page1:
    for j in page2:
        counter = 0
        for session in sessions:
            counter += ((i in session) and (j in session))
        coocurrence.append(counter)
```

I expect as an output a list called "coocurrence" where coocurrence[i] is the number of times list1[i] and list2[i] appear together in sessions.

In this example, that would be:

```py
[2,1,1,2,2,2]
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? I'm originally using PySpark, but have no idea how this could be parallelized...

Comment: What is the structure of your dataframe? Please include df.printSchema() to your question.

Comment: So do you want to count number of coocurences for each pair of pages or only for those which are presented in the lists?